# ServiceFabric nodejs application message delivery guarantee

Tags: node.js, azure-service-fabric

Can ServiceFabric guarantee at-least-once message when running nodejs applications (interprocess communication)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Service Fabric makes it easy for two services to find each other (using the naming service) but the communication protocol and associated semantics between those services is up to you.